# python bar chart total label on bar

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
plt.figure(figsize = (8,5))
sns.countplot(data = HRdfMerged, x = 'Gender', hue='Attrition').set_title('Gender vs Attrition')
```

I'm having a hard time adding a label to the top of my bar that states the total number. I have tried many different ways but can't get it right. Im using matplotlib. Picture of bar chart added.

[image: bar chart image]

Comment: Retrieve the coordinates of the bars and use `ax.text` to add the numbers where you want.

Comment: @Guimoute thank you, how would I retrieve the coordinates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have called `sns.countplot`, we will explore the list `ax.patches` to get information from the bars and place the texts you want:

[image]

```py
# Imports.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

# Load a dataset to replicate what you have in the question.
data = sns.load_dataset("titanic")
fig, ax = plt.subplots() # Use the object-oriented approach with Matplotlib when you can.
sns.countplot(data=data, x="class", hue="who", ax=ax)
ax.set_title("title goes here")
fig.show()

# For each bar, grab its coordinates and colors, find a suitable location
# for a text and place it there.
for patch in ax.patches:
    x0, y0 = patch.get_xy()   # Bottom-left corner. 
    x0 += patch.get_width()/2 # Middle of the width.
    y0 += patch.get_height()  # Top of the bar
    color = patch.get_facecolor()
    ax.text(x0, y0, str(y0), ha="center", va="bottom", color="white", clip_on=True, bbox=dict(ec="black",
                                                                                              fc=color))
```

Play around with the kwargs of `ax.text` to get the result you prefer. An alternative:

```
ax.text(x0, y0, str(y0), ha="center", va="bottom", color=color, clip_on=True)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the convenient [`Axes.bar_label`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.bar_label.html) method here to do this in just a couple lines.

Since `seaborn` does not return the `BaContainer` objects to us, we will need to access them from the `Axes` object via `Axes.containers` attribute.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

data = sns.load_dataset("titanic")
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sns.countplot(data=data, x="class", hue="who", ax=ax)

for bar_contain in ax.containers:
    ax.bar_label(bar_contain)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I tried that and received: AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'bar_label'

Comment: `bar_label` was added in [matplotlib version 3.4.0](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/prev_whats_new/whats_new_3.4.0.html?highlight=bar_label#new-automatic-labeling-for-bar-charts) so you'll need to update your matplotlib version to use `Axes.bar_label`